# Como reproduzco audios al tocar un botón desde javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hola soy nuevo en esto de la programación y necesito ayuda, la idea es crear distintos botones y que al dar clic reproduzca un audio diferente... tratar de que en el codigo de js haga el llamado del recurso del audio desde el js dentro de la function y que los audios se reproduzcan en un solo reproductor.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español!  Léete [ask] y realiza el [tour] para aprender cómo formular buenas preguntas que sean aceptadas por la comunidad. En este caso no lo es porque se espera que muestres algun error de código, incluyendo el código en modo texto, pero no lo has hecho, y es probable que cierren tu pregunta y/o recibas votos negativos. Aqui no hacemos código a medida, arreglamos fallos de código más bien, pero el que pregunta debe aportarlos.

Comment: Por favor, si te funciono la repuesta recuerda "ACEPTAR" para que otros Usuarios se beneficien de ella.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada Bienvenido a stackoverflow

Aquí te paso el código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Player Audio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls id="mireproductor" src="">Su Navegador no Soporte audio</audio>

<div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('mireproductor').src = './By_Me.mp3'">Cargar Cancion</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('mireproductor').play()">Reproducir</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('mireproductor').pause()">Pausa</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('mireproductor').load()">Parar</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('mireproductor').volume += .1">Subir volumen</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('mireproductor').volume -= .1">Bajar volumen</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

En el primer botón encontrarás el ejemplo que buscas en JS, es allí donde le pasas el nombre de la canción y se lo asignas al `src`, con esto tienes la base de programación para realizar cualquier diseño de playlist que quieras con solo cambiar o asignar un valor a ese src.

Espero que te funcione y si es así, por favor darle aceptar a la respuesta para que otros de esta comunidad puedan alimentar sus conocimientos.

¡Saludos!

Comment: Hola, me sirvió, ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta para que otros puedan utilizarla...Saludos!